# How can I decorate a Python function without changing the names of the arguments?

Tags: python, python-decorators, keyword-argument

The following Python code defines a logger and a factorial function, then calls the factorial function with a keyword argument:

```
def logger(f):
  def f_(a):
    print("Call", a)
    return f(a)
  return f_

# @logger # uncomment this line to see the problem
def factorial(n):
  return 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)

print(factorial(n=5))
```

resulting in the following output (as expected): `120`.

Now if I uncomment the logger decorator, I get an error, because the name of the argument has become `a` instead of `n`:

**How can I decorate a function (like factorial) without changing the names of the arguments?**

Comment: Have you considered using the same variable name? `f_(n)`

Comment: also consider using python logger module - I think its very good and there is no need to write your own

Comment: I don't really get your point here, why are you calling the `factorial` function with a keyword argument where you haven't defined any? If you just call `print(factorial(5))` it works fine....but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here...

Comment: @toti08 Probably a beginner that doesn't understand `kwargs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the decorator syntax, here's what you're doing:

```
def logger(f):
    def f_(a):
        print("Call", a)
        return f(a)
    return f_

def factorial(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)

# `factorial` is `def f_(a):` now
factorial = logger(factorial)
```

So to simply remedy this, use the same declaration, or don't use keyword arguments `(n=5)`

---

The better way to correct this is to use unpacking in your inner function:

```
import functools

def logger(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def f_(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Call", f.__name__, *args, *[f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()])
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return f_
```

---

[Here's a useful article on the topic.](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)